# Limit choice field selections in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

How do I limit the amount of times a specific Choice from a dropdown can be chosen in Cognito Forms?

For instance, I only want the first item to be chosen 3 times, the second item is limited to 6 times and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You can limit selections in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) by assigning [quantity limits](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/18/building-forms/limiting-quantities) to your choice fields.  Simply do the following:

1. Select **Limit Quantities** under *Choice Options*
2. Enter quantities for each choice, or leave blank for unlimited
3. Enter the **Quantity Exceeded Error Message** to something like *Out of stock!*

You can learn more about quantity limits in our [help documentation](http://help.cognitoforms.com/limiting-quantities)!

[image: limit quantities in choice fields for Cognito Forms]